# My model accuracy stays the same (0.024) after first iteration, what can i do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've created a model to predict housing prices in LA, and what should be a simple regression problem, is giving me headache because the loss is just too big and my accuracy wont change.

I've already tried normalizing, changing the architecture (decreasing layers, hidden units), adding dropout, changed the loss function, batch size, epochs and my accuracy is still only 0.024

```
input_shape = X_train_2[0].shape

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=300, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=300, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'lecun_normal', activation='linear')
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_2, y_train_2, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
model.summary()
model.evaluate(X_test_2, y_test_2)
```

I was thinking my model was going to give actual good results, cause i've already did a housing prices model when i was starting in ML, but i think i overlooked it.

Comment: If it fluctuates around 0.024. it's one problem. If it stays exactly 0.024 on each iteration, the problem is different. So, what's your case? It would be useful to add training log for several iterations

Comment: Oh, sorry, i’m not home now, but after one or two iterations stays at 0.024 and doesnt change